# Run timer in background in visual basic form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

first I'm new in this, and I have this code that shows a prompt to restart or postpone the restart for a while, the issue is that i want to hide the message and bring it back after the time specified by the user.

I'm using a "visual basic form" and the time that restart will be postponed it's selected from a "ComboBox"

My code is as follows.

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.SerializableAttribute

Public Class Form2

    Dim PostponeReboot As Integer = 50

    Private Const CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON As Integer = &H200
    Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim myCp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle Or CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON
            Return myCp
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form1.Hide()
        Label4.Text = SystemInformation.UserName
        Button1.Enabled = False
        ComboBox1.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            CheckBox2.Enabled = False
            Button1.Enabled = True
            ComboBox1.Enabled = False
        ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = 0 Then
            CheckBox2.Enabled = True
            Button1.Enabled = False
            ComboBox1.Enabled = False
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox2.Checked Then
            CheckBox1.Enabled = False
            ComboBox1.Enabled = True
            Button1.Enabled = True
        ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked = 0 Then
            CheckBox1.Enabled = True
            ComboBox1.Enabled = False
            Button1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.Text = "1 Hora" Then
            PostponeReboot = 10
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2 Horas" Then
            PostponeReboot = 20
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "4 Horas" Then
            PostponeReboot = 40
        ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "Seleccione" Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            MessageBox.Show("Rebooting")
            'Shell("shutdown -r -f -t 60")
            Form1.Close()
            End
        ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked Then
            MessageBox.Show(PostponeReboot)
            Timer1.Start()
            Me.Hide()
        End If

        If PostponeReboot = 0 Then
            Me.Show()
        Else
            Me.Hide()
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        PostponeReboot = PostponeReboot - 1
        'Label5.Text = PostponeReboot
    End Sub

End Class
```

In the first "If" sentence of below I want to start the timer and hide the form, and in the second "If" i want to bring it back the form, but the form remains hidden.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                MessageBox.Show("Rebooting")
                'Shell("shutdown -r -f -t 60")
                Form1.Close()
                End
            ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked Then
                MessageBox.Show(PostponeReboot)
                Timer1.Start()
                Me.Hide()
            End If

            If PostponeReboot = 0 Then
                Me.Show()
            Else
                Me.Hide()
            End If

        End Sub
```

I've tried putting the second "If" sentence in another place but don't work, what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume here that your Timer1 class raises the Timer1.Tick event every x time after Timer1.Start() is called. The fact that the form can hide tells me Timer1.Start() isn't a blocking method. As such, your second if statement will be verified right after you hide the form, without waiting for the `PostponeReboot` variable to reach zero. This particular button handler would then exit and your form would remain hidden. What I see is that you already have an event handler for each tick of your timer. Why not use this handler to verify the state of your `PostponeReboot` variable?

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    PostponeReboot = PostponeReboot - 1

    If PostponeReboot = 0 Then
        Timer1.Stop() 'I would assume
        Me.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Although, I would recommend you to try other solutions, like having your timer raise an event only when it reaches the elapsed time (so you don't have to handle each ticks unnecessarily). I would also recommend looking into an Universal Windows App with Toast Notifications as you could set a Notification to appear at a set time (handled by Windows) so that you don't have to have a thread running in the background for this.

Comment: It's true, so basic and i forgot to put in the PostponeReboot variable reaches the "0" and continues with -1, -2, -3 and so.